# I was going through Jordanization by Jonathan Nilsson.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, polynomials, matrix-decomposition

I was going through [Jordanization](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_0pb64o_NAhVGQo8KHa8EBTQQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstudentportalen.uu.se%2Fuusp-filearea-tool%2Fdownload.action%3FnodeId%3D654396%26toolAttachmentId%3D129072&usg=AFQjCNEJ0o7LHfkRYQLfG8349iflpNhl8w) by Jonathan Nilsson. Here he describes the algorithm for Jordanizing any square complex matrix $A$.

Here $T := (A - \lambda I  )$. Now finding the sub spaces $Im(A - \lambda I )^k$ for each $1 \leq k \leq m_{\lambda}$, where $m_{\lambda}$ is the exponent of $(t − λ)$ in $p_A$, the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

But here he claims that ...for higher $k$ the images will all be the same.

I am getting stuck here. Help Needed..

In the paper he also have explained the matrix algorithm using an example.

Thank You...

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true even in a more general context. Let T be any linear map on a finite dimensional vector space V.

Then $V \supset T(V) \supset T^2(V) \supset T^3(V) \supset \cdots$

Taking the dimension of this sequence we obtain a decreasing sequence of nonnegative integers, which has a lowest value. This means that the sequence of subspaces stabilizes:

$T^{n+1}(V)=T^n(V)$ for some n. In other words, the subspaces $Im T^k$ are all equal for $k \geq n$.